# MVC calling a method in another non-MVC project in the same solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've a C# solution that consists of an MVC project and a Windows Application project. Is there any way for MVC to call a Windows Application method and pass values to it?

I added Windows Application to References in the MVC project. But when adding the namespace reference `using Windows Application name` in the MVC class, it can't be found.

I appreciate any pointers.

Comment: That should work.  Double check your namespace.  Check build order.

Comment: Yes, check your build settings. Did you make the classes public?

Comment: The Application class is by default `internal`. (This is what C# defaults to when you create a class) You will have to change this to `public`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that classes are public (else you can't call methods from the class) and that you have added reference to the project in your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Take the code that's shared between the two, add a class library, and place it in there. That's what they are for. Past this, referencing a Windows application (`.exe`) is sure to be an issue even further down the road.

Comment: I agree that this is the ideal solution.  However, this does not explain why the reference fails.  Changing from a an EXE to a DLL doesn't explain it.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, right you are sir. I'm guessing a little code snippet would help solve that.